# What's Permaswage / Harrison tube repair?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

In modern aircraft, damage of hydraulic tubes can be repaired by Permaswage/Harrison provided by maintenance manuel. However, What is Permaswage / Harrison? It's a name of company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google for "Permaswage/Harrison" reveals that

> [Permaswage](https://www.permaswage.com/) is the technology leader in the fluid fitting industry providing proprietary and standard components, tooling, and training to all major aerospace companies globally.

"[Harrison](http://www.saywell.co.uk/products/manufacturers-supported/eaton-aerospace/internal-swage/)" seems to refer to a variety of internal swage fittings that are separable ridge tube end fittings commonly used in aerospace fluid transfer applications:

> They are also referred as “Harrison”, “Stanley Aviation” or “Sierracin” fittings, due to the history of the product.

From this, I would deduce that one can use these products to effect a repair to hydraulic lines with these methods/products because:

> Internal swaging is a mechanical method for the attachment of fittings to tubing. This is accomplished by forming tubing outward into grooves within the fitting.

<sup>--From the "Harrison" link</sup>